# UILocal notifications not showing

Tags: iphone, ios5, uilocalnotification

I can't get my local notifications to show. I am testing on the iphone. They do not show up at all and the date generated seems to be an hour before the one entered. 19 becomes 18 and so on.

How do I enable these local notifications at 7 while taking into account the user's time zone?

```
   NSCalendar* myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [myCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setHour: 19];
    [components setMinute:00];
    NSDate *todayAt7 = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];



UILocalNotification *dailyNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
dailyNotification.fireDate = todayAt7; // set this to 7pm 
dailyNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; 
dailyNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
dailyNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
dailyNotification.alertBody = @"You need to enter data for today.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that when you are creating he components instance, you are not asking for the hour and minutes components. Also, you should use `NSCalendar *myCalendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];` instead of currentCalendar.

Second issue, at least your not showing the code for it, but you're not actually scheduling the notification object. See `[UIApplication scheduleLocalNotification:]`.

Comment: I wasn't scheduling indeed! I still have the issue with the hour difference even after asking for the hours:

 NSDateComponents* components = [myCalendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit)  fromDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: Try `NSCalendar *myCalendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];`

Comment: ok seems to work now even though in the NSLog of the date it shows an hour earlier than what's entered in the components. Weird.